# Laravel slow sending emails

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have some problems with sending emails in laravel.
I build simple function to add to database and send email to user, and everything works fine. But the problem is that emails are sending slow.
This is an example that loads 0.8s on Postman

```
public function createTicket(Request $request)
    {
        $ticket = TicketSupport::create(['user_id' => Auth::id() , 'user_product_id' => $request->product_id, 'title' => $request->title, 'description' => $request->description, 'status' => 1, ]);
        
        //Mail::to($request->user())->queue(new NewTicket($ticket));

       //$data = 'test';
       //NewTicketEmail::dispatch($data);

        return response()
            ->json(['message' => 'Ticket is created!'], 200);
    }
```

When you uncomment any of methods for sending an email, it loads more than 2s.
Is there any fix for that?

Comment: what queue driver are you using?

Comment: Yup that was the problem :) I was using sync, now is database, but now is not sending an emails

Comment: are you running a queue worker?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't run it in --daemon mode :/